# Error in dynamic vertical position of controls in System.Windows.Form.Panel

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code:

```
public void KapitelOpenClose(Panel panel)
{   
    int top = 0;
    foreach (Control control in panel.Controls)
    {
        control.Top = top;
        top = control.Bottom + 1;
    }                            
}
```

It puts a list of Controls below each other. It works well when I initialize the Panel with my controls.

After I have changed the Height of one of the controls the method is called again. Sometimes It works nice, but at other times the Controls are rendered lower and lower on the Panel. They are still nicely placed below each other, but they are placed as if the start value "top" variable was higher than 0. When examining the Controls collection all the controls have the desired Top - value.

The displacement can be about 20 pixels other times about 500 or 1000 pixels, with the same Controls.

Comment: Why not use flow or table layout that already works?

Comment: @Phil1970 I give it a try. Thanks. But I am curious (anoyed) why I can't control the behaviour of the Panel.

Comment: The real problem is probably with the code you don't show! When this function is called? The problem is probably that the function is called recursively in some cases. Add a static counter and put a breakpoint if the function is called again then observe the stack trace and the behavior.

Comment: @Phil1970. No recursive calls. I start my rewrite with Flowpanel. thanks again.

Comment: Well, we cannot tell you why your code does not works since you have not provided a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That happens when you call this method when the panel is scrolled. Panel scrolls any of its child controls by adjusting their Location, much like you do in this code. When you scroll down, those controls move up by virtue of their Top property becoming negative. Starting back at 0 therefore moves them down again. The fix is very simple, don't start at 0 but at the panel's AutoScrollPosition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my code as suggested by Phil1970 and it worked. I haven't tested Hans Passant suggestion, but it gives the answer to the cause of the problem. Thanks.